# Efficient structure of FirebaseRealtimeDatabase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of books. I need to show a list of books which requires a small attribute, like just `book name, author name, rating`. Each book has several attributes where some attributes are quite large, like `book description`. When a user clicks on a single book then I'll show the book description. My book class doesn't I've attribute book description, I've updated and fetched book description separately. My book class is here.

```java
public class Book{
    private String bookName;
    private String authors;
    private String edition;
    private String publisher;
    private String ownerID;

    private String groupID;
    private String coverUrl;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String bookId;
    private int readIndex;
    private float rating;
    private String category;
    private int usersRated;

    private String acceptedReqId;
    private String currentOwnerId;
    private String currentGroupName;
    private String currentOwnerName;
    private BookState bookState;

    public Book(){

    }
}
```

My firebase structure is like
[image]
So my question is **keeping description inside a single book attribute would load book description? or should I keep book description out of book as node like below? Which one is better?**
[image]